# Using JUnit for testing Apache CXF JAX-WS services

Tags: spring, cxf, junit4

I have one problem with combining Apache CXF 2.7.6, Spring 3.1.4 and JUnit 4.8. I tried multiple scenarios, but it always ends with this exception :

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'client': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.cxf.common.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.loadClass(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Class;
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:149)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:102)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1442)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:248)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105)
at sk.datalan.semweb.sestate.test.RealestateServiceTestCase.testGetOffer(RealestateServiceTestCase.java:36)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.cxf.common.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.loadClass(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Class;
at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.getJAXBClass(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:243)
at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.createDefaultDataBinding(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:223)
at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.AbstractServiceFactoryBean.getDataBinding(AbstractServiceFactoryBean.java:109)
at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.AbstractServiceFactoryBean.getDataBinding(AbstractServiceFactoryBean.java:105)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.generatedWrapperBeanClass(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:662)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.getExtraClass(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:638)
at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:484)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:690)
at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.initializeServiceModel(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:550)
at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.create(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:265)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:205)
at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:102)
at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientFactoryBean.create(ClientFactoryBean.java:90)
at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxyFactoryBean.create(ClientProxyFactoryBean.java:156)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.create(JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.java:156)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spring.JaxWsProxyFactoryBeanDefinitionParser$JAXWSSpringClientProxyFactoryBean.create(JaxWsProxyFactoryBeanDefinitionParser.java:79)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spring.JaxWsProxyFactoryBeanDefinitionParser$JAXWSSpringClientProxyFactoryBean.getObject(JaxWsProxyFactoryBeanDefinitionParser.java:83)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:142)
... 34 more
```

My test-application-context.xml is very simple :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">

<jaxws:client id="client" serviceClass="sk.package.definitions.some.SomeService" address="http://localhost:9080/some/SomeService" />
```

And my test case looks like this :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/test-application-context.xml" })
public class SomeServiceTestCase {

@Autowired
ApplicationContext context;

private SomeService someService;


@Test
public void testGetOffer() {
    someService = (SomeService) context.getBean("client");
  }
}
```

I use these three CXF dependencies :

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
<artifactId>cxf-api</artifactId>
<version>2.7.6</version>
<scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
<artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
<version>2.7.6</version>
<scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
<artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
<version>2.7.6</version>
<scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Thank you for any advice,

Marek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a mix of different versions of CXF artifacts?

check out this: [https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-5132?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel&focusedCommentId=13709765#comment-13709765](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-5132?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel&focusedCommentId=13709765#comment-13709765)

--edit--

I think the exception is caused by **cxf-common-utilities**. There is a class **org.apache.cxf.common.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils** in **cxf-common-utilities** which conflicts with class **org.apache.cxf.common.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils** in **cxf-api**

try to remove the dependency of cxf-common-utilities and see if it works

Comment: No, I read this article. I have three 2.7.6 dependency versions. The only thing which is not 2.7.6 je cxf-common-utilities (2.5.11 - the newest one) which is neccesary for wsdl2java maven plugin.

Comment: Yes, you are right, there was different ClassLoadedrUtils in cxf-common-utilities which causes it.